# How to extract data from this JSON output?

Tags: python, arrays, json

I wrote a Python YT script to pull channel and playlist information.
I have the following JSON output from my Python script:

```
{'etag': '"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/ptsLJl-r_dDEzokkl3Kso2SZgL0"',
 'items': [{'etag': '"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/9F4RmINu4drT-fTZjviHFXj3Yak"',
            'id': 'PLejO9z7yhQOxjONeDVWaAy3kX3tEcImCR',
            'kind': 'youtube#playlist',
            'snippet': {'channelId': 'UC_ANPr8IkWibKlKhmi_-H1g',
                        'channelTitle': 'haramaininfo',
                        'description': '',
                        'localized': {'description': '',
                                      'title': 'Eid Takbeerat 1440'},
                        'publishedAt': '2019-06-04T06:30:13.000Z',
                        'thumbnails': {'default': {'height': 90,
                                                   'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HcEZMA0KJDg/default.jpg',
                                                   'width': 120},
                                       'high': {'height': 360,
                                                'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HcEZMA0KJDg/hqdefault.jpg',
                                                'width': 480},
                                       'maxres': {'height': 720,
                                                  'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HcEZMA0KJDg/maxresdefault.jpg',
                                                  'width': 1280},
                                       'medium': {'height': 180,
                                                  'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HcEZMA0KJDg/mqdefault.jpg',
                                                  'width': 320},
                                       'standard': {'height': 480,
                                                    'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HcEZMA0KJDg/sddefault.jpg',
                                                    'width': 640}},
                        'title': 'Eid Takbeerat 1440'}},
           {'etag': '"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/0vwPehiWj-5tfpY0dosabZkUwbI"',
            'id': 'PLejO9z7yhQOwt7OKSMVLdAe4jeYDpZNJC',
            'kind': 'youtube#playlist',
            'snippet': {'channelId': 'UC_ANPr8IkWibKlKhmi_-H1g',
                        'channelTitle': 'haramaininfo',
                        'description': '',
                        'localized': {'description': '',
                                      'title': 'Makkah Taraweeh 1440 (2019)'},
                        'publishedAt': '2019-04-27T13:28:47.000Z',
                        'thumbnails': {'default': {'height': 90,
                                                   'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/h9pn4qQqJTU/default.jpg',
                                                   'width': 120},
                                       'high': {'height': 360,
                                                'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/h9pn4qQqJTU/hqdefault.jpg',
                                                'width': 480},
                                       'medium': {'height': 180,
                                                  'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/h9pn4qQqJTU/mqdefault.jpg',
                                                  'width': 320}},
                        'title': 'Makkah Taraweeh 1440 (2019)'}},
           {'etag': '"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/qUNlGZC0dbvnetbNDH5EBW_6yLA"',
            'id': 'PLejO9z7yhQOzJ068ZMLd0Zub_FOrGJ82y',
            'kind': 'youtube#playlist',
            'snippet': {'channelId': 'UC_ANPr8IkWibKlKhmi_-H1g',
                        'channelTitle': 'haramaininfo',
                        'description': '',
                        'localized': {'description': '',
                                      'title': 'Madeenah Taraweeh 1440 (2019)'},
                        'publishedAt': '2019-04-27T13:28:20.000Z',
                        'thumbnails': {'default': {'height': 90,
                                                   'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CWNlyYtUTVE/default.jpg',
                                                   'width': 120},
                                       'high': {'height': 360,
                                                'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CWNlyYtUTVE/hqdefault.jpg',
                                                'width': 480},
                                       'maxres': {'height': 720,
                                                  'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CWNlyYtUTVE/maxresdefault.jpg',
                                                  'width': 1280},
                                       'medium': {'height': 180,
                                                  'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CWNlyYtUTVE/mqdefault.jpg',
                                                  'width': 320},
                                       'standard': {'height': 480,
                                                    'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CWNlyYtUTVE/sddefault.jpg',
                                                    'width': 640}},
                        'title': 'Madeenah Taraweeh 1440 (2019)'}},
           {'etag': '"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/9ImuAJ6f9CNNHDLCZ7WY80GeT1g"',
            'id': 'PLejO9z7yhQOx8ZrJYJ3o5zckygwvtUb1R',
            'kind': 'youtube#playlist',
            'snippet': {'channelId': 'UC_ANPr8IkWibKlKhmi_-H1g',
                        'channelTitle': 'haramaininfo',
                        'description': '',
                        'localized': {'description': '',
                                      'title': 'Madeenah Witr 1440 (2019)'},
                        'publishedAt': '2019-04-27T13:27:34.000Z',
                        'thumbnails': {'default': {'height': 90,
                                                   'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Qjyd94QSutw/default.jpg',
                                                   'width': 120},
                                       'high': {'height': 360,
                                                'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Qjyd94QSutw/hqdefault.jpg',
                                                'width': 480},
                                       'maxres': {'height': 720,
                                                  'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Qjyd94QSutw/maxresdefault.jpg',
                                                  'width': 1280},
                                       'medium': {'height': 180,
                                                  'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Qjyd94QSutw/mqdefault.jpg',
                                                  'width': 320},
                                       'standard': {'height': 480,
                                                    'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Qjyd94QSutw/sddefault.jpg',
                                                    'width': 640}},
                        'title': 'Madeenah Witr 1440 (2019)'}},
           {'etag': '"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/tghRJYmcElUo0PCD23-bkBwOcZ4"',
            'id': 'PLejO9z7yhQOxx6XqB6DLvQd0-IDpb299H',
            'kind': 'youtube#playlist',
            'snippet': {'channelId': 'UC_ANPr8IkWibKlKhmi_-H1g',
                        'channelTitle': 'haramaininfo',
                        'description': '',
                        'localized': {'description': '',
                                      'title': 'Makkah Witr 1440 (2019)'},
                        'publishedAt': '2019-04-27T13:27:12.000Z',
                        'thumbnails': {'default': {'height': 90,
                                                   'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yjLrG4LVv3Q/default.jpg',
                                                   'width': 120},
                                       'high': {'height': 360,
                                                'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yjLrG4LVv3Q/hqdefault.jpg',
                                                'width': 480},
                                       'maxres': {'height': 720,
                                                  'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yjLrG4LVv3Q/maxresdefault.jpg',
                                                  'width': 1280},
                                       'medium': {'height': 180,
                                                  'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yjLrG4LVv3Q/mqdefault.jpg',
                                                  'width': 320},
                                       'standard': {'height': 480,
                                                    'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yjLrG4LVv3Q/sddefault.jpg',
                                                    'width': 640}},
                        'title': 'Makkah Witr 1440 (2019)'}}],
 'kind': 'youtube#playlistListResponse',
 'nextPageToken': 'CAUQAA',
 'pageInfo': {'resultsPerPage': 5, 'totalResults': 137}}
```

I wrote this code in Python to extract certain data:

```
pprint.pprint(jdata)

for item in jdata:
    print("Title: {}\nid: {}\nurl: {}\n".format(item['title'], item['id'], item['url']))
```

But this is the error that is returned when I run my code:

```
    print("Title: {}\nid: {}\nurl: {}\n".format(item['title'], item['id'], item['url'])) 
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

How can I extract the data properly?

Comment: You access the data like standard dictionary. Assuming `jdata` is of type `dict` you're iterating over the keys in this dictionary (so `item` is of type string). Btw. What `url` do you want to extract?

Comment: @AndrejKesely can you give me an example according to what I have coded?

Comment: `jdata['items']` should give you list of items. You can iterate this list and extract additional data.

Comment: Note that each `item` in `jdata['items']` is a dictionary corresponding to the what's in the JSON data. I mention this because some of the things you want are nested inside sub-dictionaries, so to access them you'll need to do something like `item['snippet']['title']`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nested dict and except `id` the other two (`title` and `url`) are direct/indirect child keys of `snippet` which itself is nested inside the `items` array. Thus, we should loop over this array and go deeper into the `snippet` tree to be able to access their values. Also, `url` can have values for `default`, `standard`, `high`, `maxres` and `medium`. The below snippet shows `url` value for the `default` key. You will have to modify accordingly if you want to access its value for any other resolution type.

```
In [18]: for item in json_string['items']:
    ...:     print("Title: {}\nid: {}\nurl: {}\n".format(item['snippet']['title'], item['id'], item['snippet']['thumbna
    ...: ils']['default']['url']))
    ...:
    ...:
Title: Eid Takbeerat 1440
id: PLejO9z7yhQOxjONeDVWaAy3kX3tEcImCR
url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HcEZMA0KJDg/default.jpg

Title: Makkah Taraweeh 1440 (2019)
id: PLejO9z7yhQOwt7OKSMVLdAe4jeYDpZNJC
url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/h9pn4qQqJTU/default.jpg

Title: Madeenah Taraweeh 1440 (2019)
id: PLejO9z7yhQOzJ068ZMLd0Zub_FOrGJ82y
url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CWNlyYtUTVE/default.jpg

Title: Madeenah Witr 1440 (2019)
id: PLejO9z7yhQOx8ZrJYJ3o5zckygwvtUb1R
url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Qjyd94QSutw/default.jpg

Title: Makkah Witr 1440 (2019)
id: PLejO9z7yhQOxx6XqB6DLvQd0-IDpb299H
url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yjLrG4LVv3Q/default.jpg
```

Comment: This answer worked. Thanks for the quick response.